# PySpark DF Cannot do any action

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

It has been 3 weeks since this problem started.
Long story short, my goal is to create a user-item matrix for recommendation (cosine, sad, ...).

For this I've created the code below. This first function list all the file in my HDFS so I can read all my order, my product views and my product added to cart at the same time.

These actions work fine and I can print my dataframes without any problems. When I start to do actions like .distinct on the unions of my 3 DFs, I can't do anything on my df, I can show, collect, toPandas without having a big error that I can't understand.

Error about reading parquet, but just after the reading I can read my df right so there is no issues with the reading right ?

I already tried, the write legacy format, and a lot of other stuff.

Can some of you help me ? (Feel free to ask any questions, or to request more codes/files)

Thank you !
Adrien

```py
def get_data_raw_to_df(spark, nb_months=36, id_shop="-1"):
    '''get Data'''

    filename_list_paid = get_date_list(
        spark,
        "hdfs:///" + id_shop + "/master/order",
        id_shop,
        nb_months,
        "paid_"
        )

    filename_list_cart = get_date_list(
        spark,
        "hdfs:///" + id_shop + "/master/product",
        id_shop,
        nb_months,
        "cart_"
        )

    filename_list_view = get_date_list(
        spark,
        "hdfs:///" + id_shop + "/master/product",
        id_shop,
        nb_months,
        "view_"
        )

    empty_rdd = spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD()

    schema = StructType([
        StructField('cid', StringType(), True),
        StructField('sid', StringType(), True),
        StructField('product_id', StringType(), True),
        StructField('buy_product', IntegerType(), True),
        StructField('cart_product', IntegerType(), True),
        StructField('view_product', IntegerType(), True),
    ])

    df_users_items = empty_rdd.toDF(schema)

    if len(filename_list_paid) > 0:
        df_tmp_buy_product = spark.read.parquet(*filename_list_paid)\
                                .filter("is_bot == 'false'")\
                                .select('cid',
                                        'sid',
                                        F.explode('items'))\
                                .select('cid', 'sid',
                                        col("col.product_id"))\
                                .withColumn("buy_product",
                                            F.lit(5))
    if len(filename_list_cart) > 0:
        df_tmp_cart_product = spark.read.parquet(*filename_list_cart)\
                                .filter("is_bot == 'false'")\
                                .select('cid', 'sid',
                                        'product_id')\
                                .withColumn("cart_product",
                                            F.lit(2))
    if len(filename_list_view) > 0:
        df_tmp_view_product = spark.read.parquet(*filename_list_view)\
                                .filter("is_bot == 'false'")\
                                .select('cid', 'sid',
                                        'product_id')\
                                .withColumn("view_product",
                                            F.lit(1))

    try:
        # Setup product buy
        df_users_items = df_users_items\
            .unionByName(df_tmp_buy_product
                         .select('cid',
                                 'product_id',
                                 'sid',
                                 'buy_product'),
                         allowMissingColumns=True)
        # Can do thing form here
        df_tmp = (df_tmp_buy_product.select('cid', 'sid')
                  .unionByName(
                        df_tmp_cart_product.select('cid', 'sid'))
                  .unionByName(
                        df_tmp_view_product.select('cid', 'sid'))).distinct()
# Errors from here
...
```

Error log : https://justpaste.it/2y7jc

Comment: Could you add stacktrace (the big error), perhaps the first 5 lines where it shows the type of error and a couple of lines from where it says "Caused by ...".

Comment: Done ! Added a link above !

Comment: Here is the error: " java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be ..." for `order/paid_...` files.  Somewhere in the operation for this data, it is trying to cast to Double type where it shouldn't.  I am not yet pinpointing where it is happening but could you try `spark.read.parquet(*filename_list_paid).printSchema()`?

Comment: I saw this but I was thinking "this is strange" because I only select certain columns with integer or string type ONLY.
log : https://justpaste.it/8lz94

Comment: `spark.read.option('mergeSchema', True).parquet(*filename_list_paid)` might help.   Or you could try reading this specific file. `spark.read.parquet('.../order/paid__20220324.parquet/part-00039-ff535f97*').printSchema()` to see if you have String or other types.

Comment: I got something like this, is there a way to bypass this error ? 

`Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to merge fields 'visible' and 'visible'. Failed to merge incompatible data types string and boolean
        at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$.$anonfun$merge$2(StructType.scala:590)`

Comment: I see.  that is one of the cause, I think. Schema is changed at some point.  When this happens, generally you should fix the original parquet files and cast the old schema to the new schema. First, I would start with reading the specific file (code in previous comment) and compare the schema with the schema you posted and see how much it is changed.

Comment: Also, search with "pyspark parquet Failed to merge incompatible data types", there are many resources of this failures.  If you cannot control the parquet files, you could find some workaround.

Comment: Ty I found a solution !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spark.read.option('mergeSchema', True).parquet(*filename_list_paid)` might help. Or you could try reading this specific file.

Use `spark.read.parquet('.../order/paid__20220324.parquet/part-00039-ff535f97*').printSchema()` to see if you have `String` or other types.